# How to extend application class in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest, android-application-class

I want to extend the Android application and I want to override oncreate method.
But for some reason its been very terrible...Only if I remove [Application] I am able to run it but according to this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2147/what-is-the-recipe-to-have-a-working-application-derived-class) we have to add [Application]

```
[Application]
public class MainApp : Application
{
public MainApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
{
}

public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();
    //app init ...
}
}
```

Can anybody clarify me what is the rightway to extend application class in xamarin android

**Update**

If I don't remove [application] I am exactly getting the below error

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
>   Error: Error executing task GenerateJavaStubs: Application cannot have
>   both a type with an [Application] attribute and an
>   [assembly:Application] attribute. (myapp.Droid)

If I application then it compiles but it throws following runtime error

> [AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM [AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main [AndroidRuntime] Process: com.test.myapp, PID: 6524
>   [AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   application com.test.myapp.MainApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "com.test.myapp.MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.test.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.myapp-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.test.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib,
>   /vendor/lib]] [AndroidRuntime]    at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) [AndroidRuntime]
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) [AndroidRuntime]     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   [AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
>   find class "com.test.myapp.MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.test.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.myapp-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.test.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib,
>   /vendor/lib]] [AndroidRuntime]    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380) [AndroidRuntime]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  ... 9 more

Here is my manifest [file](http://text-share.com/view/9d9107d6)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In ***AssemblyInfo.cs***

comment out

```
     #if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable=true)]
    #else
    [Application(Debuggable = false)]
    #endif
```

and move that on top of your application

```
#if DEBUG
[Application(Debuggable=true)]
#else
[Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
public class MainApp : Application
{
public MainApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
{
}

public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();
    //app init ...
}
}
```

Basically you have defined it two places that's why this problem occurs.
Commenting out in AssemblyInfo.cs and adding in the extended class will work out

FYI:

Manifest is ok

Answer (score 12):

1. Apply the ApplicationAttribute, `[Application]`, to your Application subclass to register this class in the manifest

   - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.ApplicationAttribute/
2. Add the Java/JNI constructor

   - `.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)`
   - You will receive a fault when the runtime tries to instance the Java wrapper if you do not add this....
3. Override the `OnCreate` method

   - This avoids: `[art] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods` and thus your application subclass is not instanced.

Example:

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting compilation error .... it says the file couldn't be found .. I added android:name with application

Comment: @Shiva `android:name`?, Like: `[Application(LargeHeap = true, Name = "com.sushihangover.application")]`

Comment: I entered =".application" ... it says .. it couldn't find com.test.myapp.applcation ... here com.test.myapp is my package

Comment: You have to fully qualify the "Name", xamarin does support the dot notation like andriod Java or gradle

Comment: you mean to say I have to enter com.test.myapp.application in android:name

Comment: What is the full application attribute line that you are using?

Comment: Hey guys how can i add `Xamarin.Forms.Init()` in class extending Application

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris You are looking at the wrong type of `Application`, in Android you call Forms' `Init` in the first/main activity, on iOS you call it in the AppDelegate.