# Xamarin Android: How can I Set and Get global variable

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Android, I need to store some value in global variable which can be use through out the activities.

So how can i set and get the global variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

Comment: Its for Xamarin so its not a duplicate of what you mentioned. but I think you can use that solution provided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable along with this to use the Application class in Xamarin, hopefully it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058574/how-to-extend-application-class-in-xamarin-android

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

For example, set data:

```
        var data = GetSharedPreferences("Data", 0);
        var editor = data.Edit();
        editor.PutString("name","ABC");
        editor.Commit();
```

And get data:

```
        var data = GetSharedPreferences("Data", 0);
        string name = data.GetString("name", "default");
```

And I think you could also try to use [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) and [`Resource`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class and a static variables in there.