# InvalidCastException When Casting Android.App.Application.Context

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have searched for issues similar to the one I'm experiencing to no avail, so I apologize if this question has been answered elsewhere.  I found many that seemed adjacent, but none of the answers I've found thus far have helped in my particular context.

I'm developing a Xamarin.Android app that makes use of the Application instance to store some global variables.  Here is my Application class:

```
[Register("android/app/Application", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public VariablesModel Variables { get; set; }  

    public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        Variables = new VariablesModel();
    }        
}
```

I am normally able to access this Application instance from inside of an Activity (or Activity context) by doing the following:

```
var application = (MainApplication)Application.Context;
var variables = application.Variables;
```

It is a new development that the first line of the two above throws a `System.InvalidCastException` when trying to cast to `MainApplication`.  What is especially confounding to me is that we have *shipped* versions of this app that are using the code above successfully.  It is only now in my development environment that I am unable to get it working, even when I pull those previous working versions.

The only thing that I can think is that an Android SDK update has prompted this difference in behavior, but I have yet to find any documentation (or see any useful Exceptions other than the InvalidCast) that help to clarify what I'm missing.  MainApplication is inheriting `Application`, and though `Application.Context` is listed as a `Context` type, again, this cast has worked for me in the past.

Is there something I'm missing?  What do I need to do in order to get access to the running Application instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **[Application]** mark above MainApplication class .

Something like

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public string Variables { get; set; }

    public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        //it's better to initialize property in this method 
        Variables = "123";      
    }
}
```

---

Refer to [How to extend application class in xamarin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058574/how-to-extend-application-class-in-xamarin-android).

Comment: This worked!  More specifically, adding the `Application` attribute and *removing the `Register` attribute* from my class both needed to happen in order to get the cast working again (I edited to add that above, neglected to copy it originally).

I'm most curious about what changed that prevented my original class from working.  This type of cast has had no issues in the past, and the only difference I can think of that makes sense is my Android SDK version.  Any idea why the above wouldn't work anymore?